Why ccxt load_markets().keys() differ from fetch_tickers()?
I expect the code below to produce the same numbers (2542/2542), but it actually prints (2542/430). Why is this happening? It’s particularly strange because the markets from load_markets are currently trading, yet fetch_tickers does not display them. This function should be used for active tickers.
async def debug():
    exchange = ccxt.bybit({logging_data})
    markets = await exchange.load_markets(True)
    tickers = await exchange.fetch_tickers()
    print(len(markets.keys()))
    print(len(tickers))
    await exchange.close()
asyncio.run(debug())

image
I tried to use demo mode, but result is still same.
